# Android: How to know by using service when particular android app is launched

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to know by using a service when a particular android app is launched. To perform user defined task when any desired app is getting launched, I need that particular moment to be fetched and get notified using a service. Kindly help me if this could be achievable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use UsageStatsService  through reflection-http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/am/UsageStatsService.java

refer this link if you want to know how to use reflection:
[What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)